# How to make Linq to Sql Delete Exception message more user friendly

Tags: linq-to-sql, foreign-keys, constraints, sql-delete

I would like to inform the user the exact reason why a record could not be deleted, I have this code to perform deletions:

```
try{
    var table = Context.GetTable<TRecordType>();
    lock (table) {
                    table.DeleteOnSubmit(recordToDelete);
                    Context.SubmitChanges();
                 }                
    catch (Exception ex)  {
                //Put back record                  
                throw new Exception("Could not perform dataservice delete operation", ex);
            }
```

As you can see is pretty simple, but usually the record cannot be deleted because of a foreign key constraint, so I get this SQLException with a message like: "The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Something"... The conflict occurred in database "X", table "dbo.Department", column 'DepartmentId. Now what I would really like to do is atleast inform the user that he cannot delete the record because is being referenced by this table mentioned on the exception. I'd hate having to parse text to do that, is this the only way? Also it would be really nice if I could get a reference to the record breaking the constraint so I can tell the user "you can't delete document A, as is being referenced by documents B,C and D".

Answer (score 1):

Start by catching the `SQLException` specifically, since that is what you are handling.

Second, check to make sure the exception is the one you "expect." You'll need to either handle other `SQLException`s as well, or re-throw them.

You are going to have to parse the text (sort off -- just use RegEx) because this is a message that has been returned from SQL Server. It references table names and database constraints, not objects or anything else that your application knows about.

Of course, you do have a reference to the record that couldn't be deleted, in the `recordToDelete` variable.

You also have your LINQ-to-SQL model, so you could potentially traverse the relationships to that record in order to identify the documents that reference it.